# How do I cause the iFrame to expand to full page size upon redirect?

Tags: iframe

I'm currently using an iFrame widget on my Moonfuit website for a submission form from TrafficWave. The form redirects properly however, does NOT expand to the full screen to accommodate the redirect url but is only as big as the iFrame widget.

I have experimented with other html submission forms and found that JotForm redirects and expands the iFrame properly. I would use JotForm but they do not use an auto-responder nor can I connect them to an outside A/R of my choice.

I have the code for both forms if you need to compare them.
Thanks in advance for sharing any insight you may have on this issue.  :0)

Jeannie

Comment: Please post the code of the form you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

To make iframe big as the target url html document you need to tell the page that contains the iFrame the size of the content, then you can resize the iFrame.
I faced a similar problem, I suggest you to use this plugin :

[postMessage plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/)

here there's an example specific for your case :

[I frame resize](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/)